# Upload old prestashop db to new install

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

How do I upload a database I've been working on localy to a new install of prestashop that I have just installed on ipage?
So far I've exported the db from phpMyAdmin but I'm having trouble getting it onto ipage

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move a db, you need to change variables :
- in config/settings.inc.php : update your database information
- update your local db : 
in ps_configuration => modify PS_SHOP_DOMAIN and PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL
in ps_shop_url => modify both entries

Care tables prefix.

You can also search for your `http://yourlocaldomain` in all the db and replace it correctly (search and replace function of your text editor)